# How to solve this matrix determinant?

Tags: linear-algebra

I can't solve this problem, I know that is too easy but I don't how to.

Show that
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
a+x & b+x & c+x \\
b+x & c+x & a+x \\
c+x & a+x & b+x
\end{bmatrix}
= (a+b+c+3x)[(ab+ac+bc)-(a^2+b^2+c^2)]
$$

Comment: Do you know the rules for matrix determinant?

Comment: I don't know what I did wrong. I worked with the cofactors of the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the first row from the second and third rows; this doesn't change the determinant:
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
a+x & b+x & c+x \\
b-a & c-b & a-c \\
c-a & a-b & b-c
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The cofactor of $a+x$ is
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}
c-b & a-c \\
a-b & b-c
\end{bmatrix}=
-(b-c)^2-(a-b)(a-c)=-b^2+2bc-c^2-a^2+ab+ac-bc=
ab+bc+ac-(a^2+b^2+c^2)
$$
The cofactor of $b+x$ is
$$
-\det\begin{bmatrix}
b-a&a-c\\
c-a&b-c
\end{bmatrix}=
-(b-a)(b-c)-(a-c)^2=-b^2+ab+bc-ac-a^2+2ac-c^2=ab+bc+ac-(a^2+b^2+c^2)
$$
and it's easy to show that the same is the cofactor of $c+x$. So the determinant is
$$
(a+x+b+x+c+x)(ab+bc+ac-(a^2+b^2+c^2))
$$
as wanted.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much.